# Parallels 13 internet speed is slower than the MacBook pro speed

Tags: performance, internet, parallels-desktop

How do I get the internet speed on the virtual machine the same as the Mac book internet speed? The Mac speed is 300-400 and the virtual machine is 70-120.

Comment: Are you using Bridged Network Mode?